# AWS - Connect to SQS from EC2

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-cloud

I am using the below code to fetch AWS credentials to connect to SQS.  This is my personal credential and when I deploy this code in my qa or prod env , I shouldn't be using my credentials to connect to SQS. This code will be running in a EC2 container in AWS. What are the options available for me to connect to SQS without having to explicitly provide the user id / password like I have done below?

```
@Bean
public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {

    ProfileCredentialsProvider profileCredentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
    try {
        profileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                        "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                        "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                e);
    }
    return profileCredentialsProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create an IAM Role with sufficient permissions for the API requests your app will make
- Assign the IAM Role to the EC2 instance

The AWS SDK will automatically retrieve credentials from the Instance Metadata. There is no need to provide any credentials.

See: [Working with AWS Credentials - AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)

Comment: Thanks @John. Is there a way to achieve this by using security groups?

Comment: Security Groups are network firewalls. They are unrelated to credentials.

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein